# How to align images and text when images are of varying width?

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
<div id="set"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" name="" onclick=""><img src="http://goblinhammer.com/symbols/magic 2014 (m14).gif" alt="Magic 2014 (M14)">Magic 2014 (M14)</label></div>
<div id="set"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" name="" onclick=""><img src="http://goblinhammer.com/symbols/dragon's maze.gif" alt="Dragon's Maze">Dragon's Maze</label></div>
<div id="set"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" name="" onclick=""><img src="http://goblinhammer.com/symbols/gatecrash.gif" alt="">Gatecrash</label></div>
<div id="set"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" name="" onclick=""><img src="http://goblinhammer.com/symbols/return to ravnica.gif" alt="">Return to Ravnica</label></div>
<div id="set"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" name="" onclick=""><img src="http://goblinhammer.com/symbols/magic 2013 (m13).gif" alt="">Magic 2013 (M13)</label></div>
<div id="set"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" name="" onclick=""><img src="http://goblinhammer.com/symbols/avacyn restored.gif" alt="">Avacyn Restored</label></div>
<div id="set"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" name="" onclick=""><img src="http://goblinhammer.com/symbols/dark ascension.gif" alt="">Dark Ascension</label></div>
<div id="set"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" name="" onclick=""><img src="http://goblinhammer.com/symbols/innistrad.gif" alt="">Innistrad</label></div>
```

The images are of varying width, some are 20 pixels wide, others are 17 pixels wide. I'd like the text that comes after the images to line up vertically. How can I do this?

Comment: The `img`'s in the HTML do not show up. Can you change the `src`'s to the full path of the images?

Comment: Updated HTML to full path so the images show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the img tag inside a div with display and width property.

```
<div id="set">
  <label class="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="" onclick="">
    <div class="imgContainer">
      <img src="http://goblinhammer.com/symbols/innistrad.gif" alt="">
    </div>Innistrad
  </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgContainer { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 26px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/44zMW/

Comment: That doesn't align the text. I'm trying to get the text to be aligned, similar to a column. But not using table columns. I'm trying to do this with CSS.

Comment: Oops..miss understood the question..I have updated the answer please check.